# How to use word "similar way"

Tags: word-usage

Which one is more idiomatic?

> A is defined in a similar way like B.

Or

> A is defined in a similar way to B.

Comment: If you are looking for a succinct way to express the idea:  **A and B are  defined *similarly***.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

> A is defined in a way **similar** to B.

If I have to choose one of your sentences, I'd choose the second one.

Comment: Even more concisely: "A is defined **similarly** to B."

Answer (score 1):

In standard English, something is similar **to** something else. Thus, of your two sentences, only this one is correct: "A is defined in a similar way to B." Some  British English speakers may use 'similar as', e.g. I've had similar problems as yourself. This is not accepted as correct in standard English.

[Similar (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/similar)